# bootstrap large dropdown menu different width size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap large menu the Dropdown menu don't display same width it's different from each menu. How can I solve this issues the are given below.

```css
.dropdown-header {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.dropdown-large {
  position: static !important;
}

.dropdown-menu-large {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: normal;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li ul>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large>li ul>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:focus {
  color: #999999;
}

.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-menu-large {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large>li {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large>li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
    padding: 3px 15px !important;
  }
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
  min-width: 400px;
}

.dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
  min-width: 600px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
  white-space: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="mobile navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="cablenet"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home<span></span></a></li>

          <li><a href="about.php">About Us<span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cabling<span></span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">We do provide below services:</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="services.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Structured Cabling</a></li>
                    <li><a href="TelephoneCabling.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Telephone Cabling</a></li>
                    <li><a href="CopperCabling.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Copper Cabling – Cat 5, Cat 6 and Cat 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="FiberOpticCabling.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Fiber Optic Cabling – Single Mode and Multi-Mode</a></li>
                    <li><a href="CableSupport.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Cable Support / Tray Systems installation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="CableManagement.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Cable Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="AudioCables.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Audio & Video Cables</a></li>
                    <li><a href="TelecomCable.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Voice / Telecom Cable</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ElectricalCable.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Electrical Cable</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="NetworkSwitches.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Network Switches</a></li>
                    <li><a href="24Port.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  24 Port Patch Panel Loaded with Modular Jacks - Cat3, Cat5e, Cat6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="UTPCables.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  UTP Cables - Cat3, Cat5e, Cat6 ,Cat 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="UTPPatchCords.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  UTP Patch Cords - Cat3, Cat5e, Cat6 ,Cat 7</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="24PortPatch.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  1U /2 U Horizontal Cable Management Strip</a></li>
                    <li><a href="FiberOpticCable.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Fiber Optic Cable - Indoor, Outdoor, Armoured, Multimode, Singlemode, 2, 4, 6, 12, 24 core</a></li>
                    <li><a href="TerminationBlocks.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Termination Blocks for Telephone Lines - 110 Block, Krone Block</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="FiberOpticPatchPanel.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Fiber Optic Patch Panel - rack mount, wall mount, 6, 12, 24, 48 port c/w SC, ST, FC, LC adapters, Multimode, Singlemode</a></li>
                    <li><a href="MediaConverter.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Media Converter - Multimode, Singlemode</a></li>
                    <li><a href="19NetworkRack.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  19" Network Rack - 6U, 12U, 42U, wall mount, standing, customized</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Electrical<span></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="Light.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>   We do sales and Supply varies Electrical products like Lights, FAN and Electrical Cable</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Services</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="Light.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  We do design and install electrical cabling system with safety in place.</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="Light.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  We  do install various electrical products like Lights , Fan and other electrical appliances.</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">CCTV Surveillance System<span></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  We do sales and Supply Various CCTV system as below:</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Cameras.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  IP camera with 8 Channel DVR / 16 Channel DVR/ 32 Channel DVR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Cameras.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Analog camera 8 Channel DVR / 16 Channel DVR/ 32 Channel DVR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Cameras.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  IP camera with 8 Channel NVR / 16 Channel NVR/ 32 Channel NVR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Cameras.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Various Hidden camera to secured environments</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Services</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  We do design, Install and Support services for various CCTV system to have better secured environments to protect your workplace to enhance the work productivity and to have the piece of minds .</li>
                    </a>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DAS<span></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Services</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="DAS.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Door Access System</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<!-- Main Header End -->
</header>
```

check the  DAS menu and CCTV menu width size 
both are not same width
it's possible to change the same width size for all drop down menus
am using **row** for each menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for , i have set `width:100%` to `.dropdown-menu`

```css
.dropdown-header{
 font-size:18px;}
.dropdown-large {
  position: static !important;
}
.dropdown-menu-large {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: normal;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li ul > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
}
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-menu-large {
    margin-left: 0 ;
    margin-right: 0 ;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large > li {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large > li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
    padding: 3px 15px !important;
  }
}

.dropdown-menu {
 min-width: 200px;
    width:100%;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
 min-width: 400px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
 min-width: 600px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
 padding: 5px 15px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.multi-column-dropdown {
 list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 line-height: 1.428571429;
 color: #333;
 white-space: normal;
 border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #262626;
 
}
 
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
  min-width: 240px !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <div class="main-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="mobile navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="cablenet"></a> </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home<span></span></a></li>
            
            <li><a href="about.php">About Us<span></span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cabling<span></span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">We do provide below services:</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="services.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Structured Cabling</a></li>
                      <li><a href="TelephoneCabling.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Telephone Cabling</a></li>
                      <li><a href="CopperCabling.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Copper Cabling – Cat 5, Cat 6 and Cat 7</a></li>
                      <li><a href="FiberOpticCabling.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Fiber Optic Cabling – Single Mode and Multi-Mode</a></li>
                      <li><a href="CableSupport.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Cable Support / Tray Systems installation</a></li>
                      <li><a href="CableManagement.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Cable Management</a></li>
                      <li><a href="AudioCables.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Audio & Video Cables</a></li>
                      <li><a href="TelecomCable.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Voice / Telecom Cable</a></li>
                      <li><a href="ElectricalCable.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Electrical Cable</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="NetworkSwitches.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Network Switches</a></li>
                      <li><a href="24Port.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  24 Port Patch Panel Loaded with Modular Jacks - Cat3, Cat5e, Cat6</a></li>
                      <li><a href="UTPCables.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  UTP Cables - Cat3, Cat5e, Cat6 ,Cat 7</a></li>
                      <li><a href="UTPPatchCords.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  UTP Patch Cords - Cat3, Cat5e, Cat6 ,Cat 7</a></li>
                     
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                       <li><a href="24PortPatch.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  1U /2 U Horizontal Cable Management Strip</a></li>
                      <li><a href="FiberOpticCable.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Fiber Optic Cable - Indoor, Outdoor, Armoured, Multimode, Singlemode, 2, 4, 6, 12, 24 core</a></li>
                      <li><a href="TerminationBlocks.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Termination Blocks for Telephone Lines - 110 Block, Krone Block</a></li>
                      
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="FiberOpticPatchPanel.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Fiber Optic Patch Panel - rack mount, wall mount, 6, 12, 24, 48 port c/w SC, ST, FC, LC adapters, Multimode, Singlemode</a></li>
                      <li><a href="MediaConverter.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Media Converter - Multimode, Singlemode</a></li>
                      <li><a href="19NetworkRack.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  19" Network Rack - 6U, 12U, 42U, wall mount, standing, customized</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Electrical<span></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="Light.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>   We do sales and Supply varies Electrical products like Lights, FAN and Electrical Cable</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Services</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="Light.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  We do design and install electrical cabling system with safety in place.</a> </li>
                      <li><a href="Light.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  We  do install various electrical products like Lights , Fan and other electrical appliances.</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">CCTV Surveillance System<span></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  We do sales and Supply Various CCTV system as below:</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Cameras.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  IP camera with 8 Channel DVR / 16 Channel DVR/ 32 Channel DVR</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Cameras.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Analog camera 8 Channel DVR / 16 Channel DVR/ 32 Channel DVR</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Cameras.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  IP camera with 8 Channel NVR / 16 Channel NVR/ 32 Channel NVR</a></li>
                      <li><a href="Cameras.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Various Hidden camera to secured environments</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Services</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  We do design, Install and Support services for various CCTV system to have better secured environments to protect your workplace to enhance the work productivity and to have the piece of minds .</li>
                    </a>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DAS<span></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Services</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="DAS.php"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Door Access System</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.nav-collapse --> 
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- Main Header End --> 
</header>
```

Comment: is this what you need ?

Comment: @devadinesh i give you the right answer before two days, but you give tick mark on another person who aswered one hour before

Comment: last day am give tick mark but unfortunately not update. am really sorry to say

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu {
   width:100%;
}
```

use the code above i think maybe solve the problem